# How can I export html from SvelteKit or Svelte?

Tags: html, svelte, sveltekit

How can I export pure html, css and javascript in Sveltekit (not just a html file connecting a javascript file) like Nextjs does for Reactjs site?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [adapter for static sites](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapters#supported-environments-static-sites) or apply [pre-rendering](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#prerender) to specific routes using the `prerender` flag.

Comment: is there a way without sveltekit?

Comment: @aehlke: Sure, you'll just have to do more unnecessary work yourself or find a different tool. Svelte itself is for generating components, not full pages.

Comment: I found that Astro is a good alternative for static site generation (to generate pages without any resulting JS)